# Use Javascript to Load Flash SWF file automatically after other SWF finishes playing?

Tags: javascript, flash

I basically have a series of small SWF Files. I have used SWFObject to play them, but how do I get a series of SWF videos to play sequentially even though they are separate SWF files?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for the enterFrame event, loading the next SWF file when the currentFrame reaches currentScene.numFrames/2 and start playing the next SWF when it reaches currentScene.numFrames-1.

Comment: are these events available via some sort of javascript api?